# a binding in a macro isn't resolved

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm creating a library for an API server, here's a simpliefied version of I have:

```
(defonce ^:dynamic *my-token* nil)

(defmacro def-my-token
  [token1 & body]
  `(binding [*my-token* ~token1] ~@body))
```

And the main "post" method:

```
(defn my-post-request [url1]
  (try
    (let [res (client/post (str "api/url/base" url1)
                {:body (json/write-str (:secret my-token)) ;  my-token should come from the macro
      ;......
```

And here's how I want to use it:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (def-my-token "fdsfdsfdsfds" 

    ; now "my-token" should be created and visible in "my-post-request", shouldn't it?
    (print
     (my-post-request "/some_end_point"))))
```

But it says "Unable to resolve symbol: my-token in this context"

I wonder why? doens't def-my-token, being a macros, define it? why not? And how to fix that?

UPDATE:
Also without `(defonce ^:dynamic *token* nil)` it doesn't work. Why not? 
Why isn't defining the macro enough?

Comment: `defonce` and ^:dynamic are kind of at odds.  Try `def` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you bound `*my-token*`, not `my-token`. Try:

```
{:body (json/write-str (:secret *my-token*))
```

The asterisks are just a naming convention for dynamic vars, they are still part of the actual var name.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your UPDATE:

According to the documentation for [binding](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding), you can only override **already existing** vars. That's why your solution doesn't work without establishing a root binding to your dynamic var.

Sidenote:

I would recommend doing what jmargolisvt said and use a plain `def` instead of `defonce`, as I've never seen any dynamic var definition in the wild using `defonce`.

EDIT:

> doens't def-my-token, being a macros, define it? why not? And how to fix that?

Macros by themselves don't define things, they are small programs transforming your source code in the macro-expansion step of most Lisp `REPL`'s. It could define anything you want it to, but then you should've wrote the `def` special form. What you used instead was `binding` which deals with already existing vars.
You might get more insight by toying with it in the REPL and/or reading the answer of this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932530/what-is-the-practical-purpose-of-clojures-dynamic-vars-and-binding).

If you need some further explanation why `overriding` is needed:
It's practical to conceptualize vars as stacks. The root binding that you establish with using `def` is the first layer. Everything in your program will see this value unless you put "something" over it. As you can imagine in your example having `*my-token*` seen as `nil` from your functions would cause issues.

`binding` to the resuce!

It allows you put anything "on top" of the root binding (in your case `nil`) thread-locally inside of the body it, like so:

[image: vars]

Comment: what does it have to do with overriding? why do I need it in the first place?