# Clojure - how to let the library users choose which printing function to use, to display data structures?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I'm writing a small debugging library and I would like to let users choose how to display data structures. I was imagining that users could require it in this kind of way:

```
(ns some-user-namespace
  (:require
    [clojure.pprint]
    [my.library :with-args {print-fn clojure.pprint/pprint}]))
```

Is something like this possible, and if not, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do it this way. If you really to offer this kind of setup, you could provide a configuration function to be called by the user after the import:

```
(ns some-namespace
  (:require [my.library]))

(my.library/print-with! clojure.pprint/pprint)
```

Ending function name with `!` is an idiomatic way of indicating that it's causing some side effects.

In your library it could look like:

```
(ns my.library)

(def config (atom {:printer println}))

(defn print-with! [new-printer]
  (swap! config assoc :printer new-printer))

(defn my-lib-print [foo]
  ((:printer @config) foo))
```

**EDIT**: For a solution that does not require global, mutable state you can use dynamic bindings.

Lib:

```
(ns my.library)

(def ^:dynamic *printer* println)

(defn my-lib-print [foo]
  (*printer* foo))
```

Usage:

```
(binding [my.library/*printer* clojure.pprint/pprint]
  (my.library/my-lib-print {:hello "World"}))
```

---

These are the only two ways for some kind of external, contextual configuration I can think of. The only alternative is pure higher order function:

```
(defn my-lib-print [printer foo]
  (printer foo))
```

Comment: Thank you :-) I'm trying to think of a reasonable approach which wouldn't require a mutable reference... If it was one function it would be easy: I could just create it with pprint as an argument. *time passes...* Ok, I've refactored and narrowed it down to only two functions who use pprint... Is there a non-mutable way to do that...? I might end up doing just what you said :) But right now searching for an alternative is a good thinking exercise.

Comment: I was going to accept your first answer, and you provided one more. Cheers! For my simple case right now, I'll go with `swap!`. The fact that it's global is not so bad in my current use case: it's just for a debugging library anyway, so it shouldn't affect a system's internals. But it's good to know about `binding` too.