# Is ^:dynamic an atomic keyword, or a combination?

Tags: clojure

The function of `^:dynamic` is clear (see, for instance, [clojure and ^:dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730828/clojure-and-dynamic)). My question: Is `^:dynamic` an atomic i.e. indivisible keyword? If not, are any of the below also valid? What do the operators/decorations `^` and `:` add to the expression?

```
(def ^:dynamic y 5)    -- Valid (known).
(def dynamic y 5)      -- but the rest of these? ...
(def ^dynamic y 5)
(def :dynamic y 5)
(def ^: y 5)
```

Alternatively, and maybe there's no clear answer: If `^:dynamic` is an indivisible keyword, why attach all the funny punctuation to it?

Comment: In Clojure `atomic` never refers to divisibility of data, it refers to granularity of update.

Comment: I'd be open to an alternative suggestion, @noisesmith.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration

```
(def ^:dynamic x 5)
```

is equivalent to

```
(def ^{:dynamic true} x 5)
```

In general `^` followed by a keyword or map is a [metadata](http://clojure.org/metadata) reader macro. Where followed by a keyword, it sets that keyword to true in the object's metadata map.

To summarize: `^:dynamic` is not an "indivisible" keyword; it's a metadata reader macro followed by an ordinary keyword (`:dynamic` in this case).